# Serializing a Data.Text value to a ByteString without unnecessary \NUL bytes

Tags: haskell, bytestring

With the following code, I want to serialize a Data.Text value to a ByteString.
Unfortunately my text is prepended with unnecessary NUL bytes and an EOT byte:

```
GHCi, version 9.4.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci> import qualified Data.Text as T
ghci> import Data.Binary
ghci> import Data.Binary.Put
ghci> let txt = T.pack "Text"
ghci> runPut $ put txt
"\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\EOTText"
ghci>
```

Questions:

- Why are these NUL and EOT bytes generated?
- How can I avoid them in the resulting ByteString?

PS: I the real code I put the length in front of the text

```
    foo :: Text -> ByteString
    foo txt = runPut do
        putWord32host $ T.length txt
        put txt
```

Comment: I think that is the length of the `Text` as well.

Comment: For the empty string it is eight `NUL`s, so zero length, for one character, the last one is replaced with `SOH` which means one, and so on.

Comment: @willeM_ Van Onsem Good observation! It uses 8 bytes for the length field, I need only 2 bytes or 4 bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually already encodes the length in the binary string. Indeed, if we look at the source code, [for the `Text` instance of `Binary`, we see <sup>[src]</sup>](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.1/docs/src/Data.Text.html#line-385):

> ```
> instance Binary Text where
>     put t = put (encodeUtf8 t)
>     get   = do
>       bs <- get
>       case decodeUtf8' bs of
>         P.Left exn -> P.fail (P.show exn)
>         P.Right a -> P.return a
> ```

That's not much of a surprise, we encode it to UTF-8 which produces a `ByteString`, and then use `put` on that one. But the length is added when we `put` the `ByteString` itself. Indeed, the [`BinaryString` instance of `Binary` looks like <sup>[src]</sup>](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.8.9.0/docs/src/Data.Binary.Class.html#line-625):

> ```
> instance Binary B.ByteString where
>     put bs = put (B.length bs)
>              <> putByteString bs
>     get    = get >>= getByteString
> ```

The `put` for the `ByteString` produced by `encodeUtf8` thus writes eight bytes to specify the size of the `ByteString`, this is thus the number of *bytes*, not (per se the same as) the number of characters in the `Text`.

If you would want the same effect, but without the length prefix, you can use:

```
import Data.Text.Encoding

runPut (putByteString (encodeUtf8 txt))
```

this thus omits the length header.

Comment: `putByteString` has type `putByteString :: Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString -> Put.`. However I need `Data.Text` -> ByteString

Comment: @Jogger: yes, you use `encodeUtf8` first to convert it to a `ByteString`, see edit.